# Administrar estado de usuario al expirar sesión

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, session

Tengo una base de datos mediante la cual el status de un usuario cambia dependiendo si inició sesión en mi sitio o si está desconectado. El problema con esto es que este cambio unicamente funciona si el usuario cierra la sesión de manera manual, pero si la sesión se destruye al pasar cierto tiempo, el status queda igual en "Online" y esto afecta a ciertas consultas que luego realizo hacia la BD.

Código de login

```
<?php 
    function secure($value){
        include 'conexion_be.php';
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $value);
        return $value;
    }
    session_start();

    include_once 'conexion_be.php';
    $correo = secure($_POST['correo']);
    $pass = secure($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = hash('sha512', $pass);
    $status = "Online";
    if(!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
        $validar_login = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and pass='$pass'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($validar_login) > 0){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($validar_login)){
                if($correo = $row['correo'] && $pass = $row['pass']){
                    $_SESSION['correo'] = filter_var($row['correo'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                    $_SESSION['id'] = filter_var($row['id'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $_SESSION['user'] = filter_var($row['user'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = filter_var($row['usuario'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['avatar'] = filter_var($row['avatar'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['telefono'] = filter_var($row['telefono'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['pass'] = $row['pass'];
                    $_SESSION['nombre'] = filter_var($row['nombre'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                }
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET status = '$status' WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");
            }
            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit;
```

Código para cerrar sesión

```
<?php 

session_start();
include 'conexion_be.php';
$status = "Offline";
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET status = '$status' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
if($sql){
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../acceso.php");
}?>
```

Mi consulta básicamente es cómo poder hacer que cuando se cierra la sesión de manera predeterminada, el status también cambie a "offline", y no solo cuando el usuario cierra su sesión de manera manual.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, estás actualizando la base de datos para saber si un usuario esta online u offline ?

Comment: Exacto, lo que intento luego es hacer un array de todos aquellos usuarios que esten online, pero el error es que las sesiones de mi web expiran luego de un determinado tiempo y al suceder eso, el cambio de estado a offline no se ejecuta, unicamente lo hace si el usuario cierra la sesion por su propia cuenta